# Why doesn't my programmatic media query work (React.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const [smallerScreen, setSmallerScreen] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const list = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 56.25em)")

  const handler = list => {
    setSmallerScreen(list.matches)
  }

  handler(list)

  list.addEventListener(handler)

  return () => {
    list.removeEventListener(handler)
  }
}, [])
```

I would like to update my UI programmatically when the viewport gets to a certain width, but my code throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments 
required, but only 1 present.
```

When reading the docs at mozilla I only see one argument passed to the handler function, so I don't understand this error. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the returned list it is `addListener`/`removeListener`

```
useEffect(() => {
  const list = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 56.25em)");

  const handler = list => {
    setSmallerScreen(list.matches);
  };

  handler(list);

  list.addListener(handler);

  return () => {
    list.removeListener(handler);
  };
}, []);
```

[Receiving query notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries#Receiving_query_notifications)

[image: Edit Programmatic Media Query with React Hook match addListener]

You can alternatively attach `handler` callback to the window `resize` event.

```
export default function App() {
  const [smallerScreen, setSmallerScreen] = useState(false);

  const handler = () => {
    const list = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 56.25em)");
    setSmallerScreen(list.matches);
  };

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    handler(); // invoke once when mounting

    window.addEventListener('resize', handler);
    
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handler);
    };
  }, []);

  ...
}
```

[image: Edit Programmatic Media Query with React Hook]